# Getting error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the code

```
class Tech
  attr_reader :content, :tech_hash
  @tech_hash = Hash.new(0)
  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
    showTech(content)
  end
  def showTech(content)
    content.split.each do |word|
    @tech_hash[word] += 1
    end
    @tech_hash = @tech_hash.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.to_h
    p @tech_hash
  end
end

class Digital
  def analyze()
    File.foreach('test.txt') do |content|
      ob = Tech.new(content)
    end
  end
end

digi = Digital.new()
digi.analyze()
```

Here is the error

```
D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:10:in `block in showTech': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:9:in `each'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:9:in `showTech'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:6:in `initialize'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:22:in `new'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:22:in `block in analyze'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:20:in `foreach'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:20:in `analyze'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/Tech.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@tech_hash` is defined outside of an instance method, what makes it a class variable. Therefore within `showTech` there is still no `@tech_hash` instance variable defined and therefore it returns `nil`

Just move `@tech_hash` into the `initialize` method to initialize an instance variable:

```
def initialize(content)
  @content = content
  @tech_hash = Hash.new(0)

  showTech(content)
end
```

Comment: Do you happen to know a good reference answer to this question? It'll be asked over and over, until the end of times.. :(

Comment: It makes it “class instance variable,” which is not a “class variable.” The latter has different meaning in Ruby and is denoted with double at `@@var`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Cue Jörg W Mittag showing up and telling you that there's no such thing as "class instance variable" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will argue :)

Comment: The thing you call a _class variable_, I would call a _class hierarchy variable_.

Comment: @spickermann: that would be incorrect. The term for those __is__ "class variable": https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_variable_set. And what you call a "class variable" is just a regular instance variable, just on another object. I myself also use the slightly incorrect term "class instance variable" to quickly disambiguate the two scopes of instance variables.

Comment: I agree that it is slightly incorrect. But IMO using the terms _local_, _class_ und _class hierarchy variable_ makes it much easier to discuss things than using the correct terms: _instance_, _instance (on the class)_ and _class variable_ - especially because of _instance (on the class) variables_ are more common than _class variables_. Btw: I wonder if this hairsplitting helps the OP to understand the issue?

Comment: @spickermann: "I wonder if this hairsplitting helps the OP" - probably not. But we nerds simply must argue about correct terminology :)